# How do I instruction ld to look for additional directories with c?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm asking the solution in `c` , NOT command line options.

The reason I'm sure it exists is that Apache can be instructed to loaded `.so` **dynamically**:

```
load modules/mod_perl.so
```

**UPDATE**

Isn't it too inefficient if I need to search with `dlsym` one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load your own modules dynamically, study the `dlopen`/`dlsym` family of functions. That's what Apache uses to load its modules. `man dlopen` has all the information.

If you want to link against shared libraries, you *must* use linker command line options to specify where these libraries are. Otherwise your program will not be able to execute. No amount of C programming can help a program that won't even start.

Comment: Do you mean Apache searches the function addresses one by one with `dlsym`? I think it's way too inefficient...

Comment: @Je Rog: Presumably, in cases where dlsym() has too much overhead, apache will cache the function pointer dlsym() returns.

Comment: There are not many symbols Apache needs to look up. Just one per module, to be precise. Look at the source! In the case of Apache it's not a function, it's a struct that holds a table of everything Apache needs to use a module. In other cases it could be a function, or a few functions. If your API is too big (more than a dozen of functions), put all the function pointers you want to export in a struct, and export that struct.